# Como puedo hacer para que el texto no se ponga borroso

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Tengo un boton dentro de un figure, este figure es hijo de elementos que tienen aplicadas propiedas transform y position absolute (esto podria influir) mi problema es que el texto del boton esta borroso, no se que hacer en este caso, si quito el contenedor padre que tiene position absolute el texto se ve normal, pero eso no es una opcion para mi

Comment: Puedes colocar el código para que podamos aportarte ideas

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.